# Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError'

Tags: android, android-testing

I am trying to test out that an async task that performs an api request in the background and returns some data. Everything runs fine when run through the emulator, but I get a `NoClassDefFoundError` when I run the written test. The class that it seems to refer to is the builder class for the Google Cloud api class. If I comment out the api call code and return a hard coded Joke the test passes.

Is there something else that has to be done to include the Google api libraries in the test?

#### Test

```
package com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger;

import android.test.AndroidTestCase;
import android.util.Log;

import org.chrisolsen.common.Joke;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class JokeTaskTest extends AndroidTestCase {

    private static final String TAG = "JokeTaskTest";
    private CountDownLatch signal = null;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        Log.d(TAG, "setUp:");
        signal = new CountDownLatch(1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        signal.countDown();
    }

    public void testTheAsyncTask() throws Throwable {
        final JokeTask task = new JokeTask(new JokeTask.JokeTaskListener() {
            @Override
            public void onJokeReceived(Joke joke) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onJokeReceived: in the listeneer");
                assertTrue(true);
                signal.countDown();
            }
        });

        task.execute();
        signal.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}

package com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.json.AndroidJsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleClientRequestInitializer;

import org.chrisolsen.backend.myApi.MyApi;
import org.chrisolsen.common.Joke;

import java.io.IOException;

public class JokeTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Joke> {

    public interface JokeTaskListener {
        void onJokeReceived(Joke joke);
    }

    private static final String TAG = "JokeTask";
    private JokeTaskListener mJokeListener;
    private MyApi mApiService;

    public JokeTask(JokeTaskListener listener) {
        mJokeListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Joke doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        if(mApiService == null) {  // Only do this once
            // THIS IS WHERE --+ IT SEEMS TO FAIL
            //                 V
            MyApi.Builder builder = new MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                    // options for running against local devappserver
                    // - 10.0.2.2 is localhost's IP address in Android emulator
                    // - turn off compression when running against local devappserver
                    .setRootUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/_ah/api/")
                    .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                        @Override
                        public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                            abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                        }
                    });
            mApiService = builder.build();
        }

        try {
            String text = mApiService.getJoke().execute().getData();
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: " + text);
            return new Joke(text);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "fetch: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Joke joke) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: JOKE: " + joke);
        mJokeListener.onJokeReceived(joke);
    }
}
```

#### Error details

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.JokeTask$1
        at com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.JokeTask.doInBackground(JokeTask.java:33)
        at com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.JokeTask.doInBackground(JokeTask.java:16)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
```

#### Manifest

```
    <!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <!-- This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

#### Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // Added for AdMob
    compile project(':common')
    compile project(':android')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: can you add your manifest also?

Comment: The manifest contains just the basics..is there something that has to be added there?

Comment: the application name says multi dex application why do u have that? did u exceed the 65k class limit?

Comment: Yes I did, kinda odd for a project this small though.

Comment: try removing that n see what happens

Comment: do you have this line in your gradle file `multidex = true`

Comment: After running things without multidex enabled I get a `com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException` exception

Comment: well if you are using multidex application you need to add the dependency in gradle and need to enable multidex also

Comment: Yes, the dependency is there. I updated the gradle file to show that.

Comment: What device are you running the tests on? It needs to be an emulator that has Google API's (usually written in brackets in the emulator name)

Comment: The emulator that I run it on works fine when testing it manually and I double checked to make sure that the tests are using the same one, which they are.  I am doing the test on a different emulator just to double check though.

Comment: I dont see the dependencies part in the gradle

Comment: The different emulator seemed to do the trick!! :)

Comment: Thanks for the help :)